# Use Kotlin in VSCode

Tags: java, kotlin, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get Kotlin to work inside VSCode. So far with kotlin extensions I've managed to get it working partially. I can use any Kotlin specific class or function, but I can't import any java specific class. (`error: unresolved reference`)

When I've compared the VSCode project to an Eclipse one and an IDEA one I've noticed that both have the JRE in the project folder (in IDEA case as an `External Library`).  Pretty sure that is my problem in VSCode, but I don't know how to add the JRE to my project.

I am using Gradle for my project:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines 'enable'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.21"
}
```

As you can see I have the Kotlin-JVM plugin, but apart from that I am not aware of a way of adding the JRE to gradle. Can anyone please help me out?

Edit: I've tried adding kotlin coroutines to the project only to find out that even this external library won't work (I am getting the unresolved reference error both on the `import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.*` and on the `async` function). This makes me believe that gradle isn't aware of the actual project and won't import any required dependencies.

When created the project I've used the `gradle init` command, modified the `build.gradle` file and then created a `main.kt` file at the root of the project (no actual code in the file, just the main function, the import statement and a call to `async`)

Comment: You don't add the JRE to gradle. Set the `JAVA_HOME` variable globally and gradle should be able to find it. If you are running Linux, this should be done by your distro when installing Java, but otherwise `/etc/profile` is a good place to define the variable. Otherwise, I recommend changing the OS on the long run and use Google to find a temporary solution

Comment: I am on windows. I've set up the variable, but it still won't let me import the java class

Comment: @msrd0 I've edited the post adding a couple extra information. If you are kind enough, reread it

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I've only ever used Idea & Atom on Linux. If `gradle init` works this means gradle can find the JRE (gradle cannot launch without it). Try `gradle assemble` to see whether your problem is with gradle or with VSCode

Comment: @msrd0 The command worked. Also, when I've added the coroutine, VSCode syntax check would mark the call to `async` as an error, but after a restart that syntax error is gone and I even get the documentation reference, so is not from VSCode. I am thinking I am running the code with the wrong command or I need some specific folder structure. If you've used Atom,what command did you use to build the project?

Comment: I haven't used Atom to build or run my project, only for the Kotlin plugin to find the classpath. Therefore, I created a gradle task to export the classpath, you can find this when you google the plugin. I've then used my shell to run all the gradle tasks, like `gradle assemble`, `gradle build` and `gradle run`

Comment: This is however something I can only suggest Linux/Unix users as the Windows Command-Line (I'm not going to call that a shell) is not usable for development on a daily basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured it out. So, what I had to do was to add the gradle application plugin and run my code with it

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

  ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'MainKt'
defaultTasks 'run'

run{
  standardInput = System.in
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And then run the code with `gradle run`